# Calcite Predicate Push Down

Tags: sql, predicate, apache-calcite

Source SQL

```sql
SELECT  e . *
FROM    emp e
INNER JOIN    dept d
ON      e.deptno = d.deptno
AND     emp.deptno = 5;
```

After Optimzie

```sql
select
  e.
from
  (
    select
      *
    from
      emp
    where
      emp.deptno = 5
  ) e
  inner join (
    select
      *
    from
      deptno
    where
      deptno = 5
  ) on on e.deptno = d.deptno;
```

Does Calcite have this optimization rule?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there was `CoreRules.JOIN_CONDITION_PUSH`.
But the only emp.deptno = 5 can be pushed into table emp.
The transitive conditioin can be implement by your self.